# How to combine multiple crosstabs while preserving same binary column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I would like stack 2 crosstabs for 2 categorical variables (gender, race) while preserving the same binary variable (goal) as columns.

Take for example this dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'GenderDSC':['Male','Female','Female','Male','Male','Male'],
             'Goal':[0,1,0,1,0,0],
             'Race':['African-American','White','White','Asian','Asian','White']})
df
```

Where crosstabs would output:

[image]
[image]

But would like them to be merged like:

[image]

So far, I have tried:

```
a = pd.crosstab(df['GenderDSC'],df['Goal'])
b = pd.crosstab(df['Race'],df['Goal'])
pd.concat([a,b])
```

[image]

But I lose the groups for each columns (genderdsc, race), so thinking there could be a better way to connect them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the argument [`keys` from `pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```
>>> pd.concat([a,b], keys=('GenderDSC', 'Race'))
```

From the docs,

> If multiple levels passed, should contain tuples. Construct hierarchical index using the passed keys as the outermost level.

---

```
Goal                        0  1
GenderDSC Female            1  1
          Male              3  1
Race      African-American  1  0
          Asian             1  1
          White             2  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) the data:

```
tmp = df.melt('Goal')
# if you want custom names
# tmp = df.melt('Goal', var_name='variable', value_name='value')

out = pd.crosstab([tmp['variable'], tmp['value']], tmp['Goal'])
```

Output:

```
Goal                        0  1
variable  value                 
GenderDSC Female            1  1
          Male              3  1
Race      African-American  1  0
          Asian             1  1
          White             2  1
```